# How to localize laravel in routes

Tags: laravel, routes, localization

I am trying to view multilingual articles when i click to read more button on blog page

**blog page view(blog controller and view working fine)**

```
 @foreach($leg as $sost)
<div>
<a href="{{route('view-post', ['lang'=>app()->getLocale(), 'slug'=>$sost->slug])}}> {{ $sost->title }}
                            
</div>
    @endforeach
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('{lang}/article/{slug}', 
[App\Http\Controllers\frontend\personal\mycash\mycashcontroller::class, 'view'])->name('view-post');
```

**MycashController**

```
  use App\Models\mycash;
  public function view( $lang,$slug)
   {
   $post = mycash::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('frontend/Personal/articles',compact('post' , 'lang'));
   }
```

**Article View blade**

```
                <div>
                    <p class="text-left" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">{!!$post->content !!}</p>
                </div>
```

**My results**

On clicking on the link I am getting an error of [URI: {lang}/article/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug]

What wrong am i doing?

Comment: Your `href` is missing a closing `"`. Your `<a>` is missing a closing `</a>`. Have you made sure that `$sost->slug` actually contains something? What's the URL you're being taken to?

Comment: i have the closing tags okay but still brings me the error...The url it takes me is localhost:8000/en/article/blog_1

Comment: Am getting this error Missing required parameter for [Route: view-mpost] [URI: {lang}/article/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug].

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php foreach($leg as $sost): ?>

<div>
<a href="<?= route('view-post', ['lang'=>app()->getLocale(), 'slug'=>$sost->slug]);?>">
<?= $sost->title; ?>
</a>                  
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: am getting this  error  Missing required parameter for [Route: view-mpost] [URI: {lang}/article/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug].

Comment: <?= $sost->title; ?> after this line, put this line  and check if your url is counstructed correctly or not, you're getting error may be because slug is not passed into the url **<?= route('view-post', ['lang'=>app()->getLocale(), 'slug'=>$sost->slug]); ?>**